# Is the WiFi-communication during installation harming my privacy?

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, installation, privacy

I want to use Android (6.0 / marshmallow) on my new device (OnePlus 3) and want to set it up as [google-free as possible (as example)](http://www.xda-developers.com/setting-up-android-marshmallow-without-google/). By default, I am forced to set up a Wi-Fi network when I boot my phone initially (or after a factory reset).

I intend to disable google services and won't use a google account. I am interested in any evidence that the communicated data during the install process does already harm my privacy protection efforts (i.e. transmitting some ID to google to track me or my device).
Does anyone know if that is the case in the set up process (i.e. did someone invest this further with wireshark etc. already?)

**Update:** After a hard reset and new try to set it up, there is the message "This device was reset. To continue, sign in with a Google Account that was previously synced on this device." So there seems to be some anti theft magic, which also raises privacy concerns.

Comment: You could just sign in, and then remove the account and turn off your gps. That'll help. Your setup process is not leaked online- its all local, the internet is just for backup/restore/google sign-in. A good 'ol adb based logcat proves it.